# Make QListWidget only show 1 item

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qlistwidget

I have created a class that inherits the QListWidget and is meant to be a stack of cards.

I have overloaded the drag and drop functions to allow a card to be dragged to the table (another object of my program) and now I stumble on another problem.

The QListWidget shows all my items (mainly because I add them to the GUI from the beginning).

So this is how it goes:
in my mainwindow I initialise my CardPile object and fill it up with a shuffled vector of cards.

Now I want my QListWidget to show only one (but its showing a grid with all my cards).

On a drop I remove the item from my QListWidget. But I have no idea if I were to add and remove 1 card at a time (so it only shows 1 card ofcourse) in my code.

```
public:
    TileStack(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void addCard(QPixmap pixmap, QPoint location);
    QPixmap showCard();

protected:
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
    void startDrag(Qt::DropActions supportedActions); //in this function I remove the current item
```

These are the functions in my CardPile : QListWidget.

so:

```
void TileStack::startDrag(Qt::DropActions /*supportedActions*/)
{
    QListWidgetItem *item = currentItem();

    QByteArray itemData;
    QDataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QPixmap pixmap = qVariantValue<QPixmap>(item->data(Qt::UserRole));
    QPoint location = item->data(Qt::UserRole+1).toPoint();

    dataStream << pixmap << location;

    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
    mimeData->setData("card", itemData);

    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
    drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
    drag->setHotSpot(QPoint(pixmap.width()/2, pixmap.height()/2));
    drag->setPixmap(pixmap);

    if (drag->exec(Qt::MoveAction) == Qt::MoveAction)
        delete takeItem(row(item));
    //should I also make the add to the next item here? and how exactly should I put it     here?
}
```

Because I currently have my vector of shuffled cards in the mainwindow (where I add all the cards in a forloop).

Or should I make a signal and slot that connect between mainwindow and CardPile - so when

```
delete takeItem(row(item));
```

is called I emit a signal that says to add the next card to the list?

Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`QStackWiget`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qstackedwidget.html#details) (the first line of the desription is exactly what you want to ahieve) instead of a QListWidget.

Comment: Yes, I have thought about that. but inside this widget I am using QListWidgetItem to fill the listWidget up. can I fill the QStackedWidget with those too?

Comment: You can not access to the list of widget but you can access all widgets by index, so I guess yes